# Drawing a Region with CSS -fx-shape. How it is possible?

Tags: css, canvas, javafx, fxml

I'm looking a way to draw shapes in a Region (JavaFX8)

I've seen some examples that set the region style like this:

```
-fx-shape            : "M 3.0313 0 L 0 74 L 7.9688 74 L 4.9375 0 L 3.0313 0 Z";
```

Can anyone give an explanation of the meaning of this string?

Is there any way to create this type of string using Visual Software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shape string is an [SVG Path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

Note the shape string for a region is the shape of the region, not a shape in a region.  If you want to create shapes based on paths to put in a region, then use an [SVGPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html) and not a [Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html).

You can use an SVG editor to create SVG paths.

Recommending particular SVG editors is off topic for StackOverflow, try Google and you may find [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) (and it's option `Path | Object to Path`).

Comment: I'm trying to learn about SVGPath and Region. Basically, they can do the same basic function, but i've not seen the differences. Do you know when to use each one?

Answer (score 0):

To gain some in-depth knowledge on how JavaFX CSS works, I'd highly recommend using Oracle's [*JavaFX CSS Reference Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Regarding the `-fx-shape` property, the *JavaFX CSS Reference Guide* indicates that this property is only applicable to `Region` objects and its subclasses.

The most essential JavaFX CSS property needed alongside `-fx-shape` for a `Region` is `-fx-background-color`, which defines the colour used to fill the shape.

If you define the following Java FX CSS class (`-fx-position-shape` & `-fx-scale-shape` are `true` by default, so there's no need to define these):

```
.my-class {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-shape: "M 33.22656,4.88086 19.9414,21.228516 10.31445,15.714844 0,27.251953 1.49023,28.583985 10.72656,18.25586 20.42187,23.808594 34.77734,6.142578 Z m 1.8,-0.66836 -1.07812,0.410157 -10.41406,3.972656 9.55468,7.763672 z";
}
```

then assign this CSS class to your region (`Pane` extends `Region`):

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getStyleClass().add("my-class");
```

and ensure that it's correctly sized, JavaFX will render an arrow in red, centered & scaled to fit the region, thus:

[An arrow created in Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyCys.png)

Inkscape's XML Editor (Menu option `Edit | XML Editor`) is ideal to extract the SVG Path to paste into your stylesheet document. Prior to using this, as already mentioned in the answer above, you'll probably need to convert any objects, such as lines or ellipses, into paths, using the `Path | Object to Path` menu option

W3C's [SVG Paths document](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) describes the format of SVG Paths in detail.