# Is it possible to select/click multiple parts of one image?

Tags: java, image, javafx

For an assignment I am making a Boardgame. (In java) This Boardgame has a map, with multiple fields/lands that have to be used. Units can be placed on them, they can move. Other things are also placed on them.

For the map I have one image I use. I looked online for solutions, but the only ones I found where for a grid game (such as chess or checkers) and the map of this game can not be divided in just squares. I tried this, but the field shapes are to different to make that work.

I had a few faint ideas as to how to work this out, but I can't quite put them into code examples and have no clue if they would work, or how.

The ideas I had:

- Make some invisible buttons and bind them to specific coordinates in the picture. The problem I had with this solution was that it also had to be able to display things placed on it. It would also be very inconvenient if not all of the field was clickable.
- I have a 'overlay' image with the outlines of all the fields and the 'insides' removed. I made this overlay so I could add a faint color overlay over the board. Would it be possible to use this in any kind of way?
- First I though of cutting out all the loose fields and putting them together to form the one image. Only, I don't know how I would do this. Not just where to place it, but also, how can I make sure that the elements are Always in the same place compared to eachother, and my board doesn't mess up when changing screen/resolution size?

I am using javafx for the graphical elements in my game.

If there are any suggestions of something I haven't thought of myself, those are also very welcome.

Comment: maybe svg will help you? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753613/javafx-button-with-svg

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know what to do with that

Comment: What exactly would I do with that?

Comment: With SVG you can make button of any shape. If you just put an image on a button it still stay square, just with image in the middle. Once you got a set of shaped buttons you can use your first approach and stick them to the map.

Comment: That would be very hard and a lot of work though, because all the fields have very different shapes, and not easy ones.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful or not, but it's pretty easy to determine the color of the pixel in the image where the mouse click occurs. If that's enough information to know what's been clicked on, that may make a viable approach.

Comment: That sounds like it could work. How would I do that? Or better, could you make an answer out of that?

Answer (score 1):

If it's sufficient to retrieve the color of the pixel where the mouse was clicked, then you can do that fairly easily. If you know the image is displayed in the image view unscaled and uncropped, then all you need is:

```
imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    Color color = imageView.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
    // ...
});
```

More generally, you may need to map the image view coordinates to the image coordinates:

```
imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    double viewX = e.getX();
    double viewY = e.getY();
    double viewW = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
    double viewH = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
    Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();
    double imgX = viewport.getMinX() + e.getX() * viewport.getWidth() / viewW;
    double imgY = viewport.getMinY() + e.getY() * viewport.getHeight() / viewH ;
    Color color = imageView.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor((int)imgX, (int)imgY);
    // ...
});
```

Once you have the color you can do some simple analysis to see if it approximately matches the color of various items in your image, e.g. check the `hue` component, or check if the "distance" from a fixed color is suitably small.

A typical implementation of that might look like:

```
// choose a color based on what is in your image:
private final Color FIELD_GREEN = Color.rgb(10, 10, 200);

private double distance(Color c1, Color c2) {
    double deltaR = c1.getRed() - c2.getRed();
    double deltaG = c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen();
    double deltaB = c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue();
    return Math.sqrt(deltaR * deltaR + deltaG * deltaG + deltaB * deltaB);
}

private boolean colorsApproximatelyEqual(Color c1, Color c2, double tolerance) {
    return distance(c1, c2) < tolerance ;
}
```

And the back in the handler you can do

```
if (colorsApproximatelyEqual(color, FIELD_GREEN, 0.1)) {
    // process click on field...
}
```

Whether or not this is a viable approach depends on the nature of the image map. If the coloring in the map is too complex (or objects are not easily distinguishable by color), then you will likely need to place other elements in the scene graph and register handlers on each of them, as you describe in the question.

Comment: The color is not gonna be a problem, because I have the 'empty' overlay and can apply the colors there.

Comment: But how would I use the space set by the color? If I wanted to place a unit there, how would that work?

Comment: @Noralie Not really sure what you're asking. Maybe put the `ImageView` in a `Pane` and add something else to the `Pane` with `layoutX` and `layoutY` set to the coordinates of the mouse click

Comment: Can I make individual objects of all the fields (all the different colors) and give them different properties? And If I want to display something on that field, can I do that directly or do I need something else for that?